# how to introspect a couchdb document for its set of fields via couchdb-python

Tags: python, couchdb

How can I get the fields for a couchdb document?  I'm thinking of how to use couchdb-python, and often will not know the complete set of fields for a document. I haven't seen anything about how to introspect a document in the docs.  What's the best way?  If the document was a python object I would query `object.__dict__` for its attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.keys() returns a list of field names.

```
db = server['test']
for doc in db:
    print doc
    for key in db[doc].keys():
        print key
```

You should get the doc id, followed by the fields.

Comment: Documents as returned by CouchDB are just plain old dictionaries with a couple of extra properties. You use them just like you would any other dict.

Comment: Thanks -- so is db[doc] a python dict?  Sorry for the naivety, I haven't had a chance to install couchdb yet to play with it.

Comment: Yeah, it is a dict.  I've only been playing with it a bit myself, while learning Python.